# return all tags from pimcore object

Tags: php, object, pimcore

is there a built in method or custom method that allows you to spit out all the tags of an object as an array?

```
$this->session = new \Zend_Session_Namespace("webUser");
    $webUser = \Pimcore\Model\Object\WebUser::getById($this->session->webUser);
    $tags = \Pimcore\Model\Element\Tag::getTagsForElement("object", $this->session->webUser);
    $this->view->tags = $tags;
    var_dump($tags);
```

ive currently got this, ignore the session user etc but this dumps out tags that are assigned to the object. I need to spit out every tag even if its not assigned. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$db =  Db::get();
$select = $db->select()
    ->from('tags_assignment', [])
    ->where('tags_assignment.ctype = ?', 'object');
$res = $db->query($select)->fetchAll();
```